# How to get wordpress blog in drupal 7 homepage

Tags: drupal

I have a website in drupal 7. How to place wordpress blog feed inside a block in drupal 7. website is in drupal domain and blog is in wordpress domain.
Currently I have both a Drupal and a WordPress site. Is there a module that can display the latest posts from my WordPress site in drupal block?

Comment: the [feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) can automagically get a feed and create content from it periodically. Then use views to create a block that displays the content types that were created by your feed importer (that read your wordpress feed)

Comment: Or you could do it on the fly with javascript so then wordpress content would not need to be imported (and taint your drupal database)

Comment: You did not really explain what you mean by "link the two" so it is hard to give specific advice.

Comment: Currently I have both a Drupal and a WordPress site. Is there a module that can display the latest posts from my WordPress site (blog) in drupal block(main website)?

Answer (score 0):

Several way available :

1 - Create a flux (rss , xml) and aggregate it with [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) or custom module (recommanded)

2 - Create service on wordpress to provide information to drupal. Custom module needed (a lot of development but handled easy)

3 - Create a listing page on wordpress and use it on drupal with an iframe (but it's not a safe way)

For all these way , you have to create a block displayed on homepage (custom module or via administration)

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know the result

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer just raw data (i.e JSON array) and then build html out of it on Drupal side. Or you can create full HTML from WP site, save a file somewhere where Drupal can access it and move file to Drupal site. In both cases do the transfer periodically, time to time (within a cron call) - don't do it for every usage (page view on Drupal side).